# Is it good practice to ALWAYS use a REST API for Razor Page specific data

Tags: rest, razor-pages

Imagine I have a Razor Page or such like. Imagine the data used by that Razor Page is not used by any other page at all. So the data retrieval is very specific to this page only.

1. Is it bad practice to just grab the data directly using a database connection from within that Razor Page local to the only place that data is to be used?
2. If so, why should I abstract the data away into a separate API that isn't re-used anywhere? Why is it good practice?

It seems to me, that REST APIs are sometimes used unnecessarily and for no good reason. As if because every example video shows data retrieval from REST APIs. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is purely a server-side app, there is no justification for creating RESTful API that serves up JSON for it. Those kinds of APIs are usually created for "external" consumers, by which I mean third parties or the browser (via JavaScript). They are commonly implemented for client side apps  - single page apps typically like React, Angular or Blazor where JSON is the data format of choice for the browser.

As to whether you should open database connections in your PageModel class, that's another question. For simple apps, why not? But for apps that need unit testing, it's not a good idea. You will be unable to execute unit test against the PageModel class without hitting the database.

As a habit, I tend to put the code that connects to a database in a series of separate classes, each one having an interface, and then inject them into the PageModel via dependency injection. That way I can mock the service represented by the interface for unit testing.

You might want to implement services that generate data as JSON within a Razor Pages app if you have some functionality that depends on Ajax requests for data.  For those, you could use Web API controllers, [minimal request handlers](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/358/using-minimal-apis-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages) or even [named handler methods](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods) that return JsonResult objects in the PageModel classes. With all of those, you might still want to put the code that actually calls the database in a separate class that is injected into the handler.

Comment: Typically, we will have a client-side web page that requests JSON data for all sorts of purposes. Data for a grid, a dynamic dropdown lookup, a dependent drop-down lookup etc.

Comment: Then you need a mechanism for returning JSON data. I've provided three alternatives, two of which (the non-Web API options) have nothing to do with REST.

Comment: At the moment, and as far back as I can remember, we have used Named Handlers. We have however been using direct database connections from within said handlers. Farming out the connection to outside the handler is something we would look at I guess now. Seems to me, doing this aspect may well benefit from still being local to the page concerned, rather than in an external API away from where the page is located though. Yeah, a separate class perhaps. Still thinking about this. Your comments are helping for sure.

Comment: If the data is mainly for the page that needs it, a named handler returning a `JsonResult` certainly helps to keep things in one place.   It's pretty simple to move the actual data access code into a separate class, generate an interface for it and then inject that into the named handler method as an argument. Then it's available elsewhere if you need it.